# jQuery mailto with anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, mailto

I tried this with umpteen examples we see on the net. But I guess there is none that is simple and works on all browsers (IE 8 and above as well).

I am trying to simply open up Outlook window with mailto link.

```
<a href="#" name="emailLink" id="emailLink">Email</a>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $('#emailLink').on('click', function (event) {
    alert("Huh");
    var email = 'test@theearth.com';
    var subject = 'Circle Around';
    var emailBody = 'Some blah';
    window.location = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' +   emailBody;
  });
});
```

Granted, I am a jQuery newbie. The above just doesn't work. It just flickers the browser but nothing opens. I guess this is because of `window.location`.

Is there a simple solution? I want this to work in IE8 & above and in all browsers.

The body is generated automatically (in JSP).

Comment: `href` is spelled wrong. also you select by id but the tag has no id

Comment: #emailLink means id="emailLink". in your case it will be [name=emailLink] http://jsfiddle.net/cwa3454s/

Comment: You also need a comma after `'click'` and before `function`

Comment: Thanks guys. I updated it with all the fixes.

Comment: here's a working version of your script http://jsfiddle.net/97ap11cu/

Comment: This seems to work. But does it work in IE8 (and above)? I will check anyway.

Comment: @krozero this works in FF too. But it refreshes the page, which should be avoided. Anything else I can change to prevent that?

Comment: @KevinRave, you can use  event.preventDefault(); in your function. here's e.g  http://jsfiddle.net/97ap11cu/2/

Comment: does this work in all browsers? (IE8 and above a swell)?

Comment: @krozero It works in IE8.. Please put this as answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

here's working solution:

```
<a href="#" name="emailLink" id="emailLink">Email</a>
```

and the function:

```
$(function () {
  $('#emailLink').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    alert("Huh");
    var email = 'test@theearth.com';
    var subject = 'Circle Around';
    var emailBody = 'Some blah';
    window.location = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' +   emailBody;
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't you need to escape special characters in `email`, `subject` and `emailBody`? What if I want to send text `Bob & Alice are friends` to e-mail `john+doe@艺龙.中国`?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need the address as a text anywhere on the website I would suggest this:

```
$('a[data-mail]').on('click', function() {
   window.location = 'mailto:' + $(this).data('mail')+'@yourdomain.net' + '?subject=Spotflow';
});
```

The link woud look like this:

```
<a href="#" data-mail="max">Send me a mail</a>
```

**No chance for bots!**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
  $('[name=emailLink]').click(function () {
    var email = 'test@theearth.com';
    var subject = 'Circle Around';
    var emailBody = 'Some blah';
    $(this).attr('href', 'mailto:' + email +
           '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' +   emailBody);
  });
});
```

.click can be replaced with .mousedown and so on.. or just

```
$(function () {
  $('[name=emailLink]').each(function() {
    var email = 'test@theearth.com';
    var subject = 'Circle Around';
    var emailBody = 'Some blah';
    $(this).attr('href', 'mailto:' + email +
           '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' +   emailBody);
  });
});
```

Comment: i would not even do a click event here. just set href on load

Comment: @LoganMurphy who knows why he wants to do it this way ) on my site I scramble email originally, restoring it after the page loads and replacing hrefs only on clicks.

Comment: @LoganMurphy Can you update/elaborate? My requirement is simple. Click the anchor link and send email using jqeury. Thats all.

Comment: @KevinRave did you try the code above? Or you can just set href onload, without attaching click listener.

Comment: @Cheery can you update your answer, would you please update the answer with that Logan said?

Comment: @KevinRave Check an answer again.

Comment: @Cheery you just replaced, click with each. Correct? I guess, its not onLoad?

Comment: @KevinRave this is ("$(function () {") a replacement for $(document).ready function - when DOM is ready your link(s) (through the function .each) will get a correct href attribute. There is not need to do it on window load, DOM ready is enough.

Comment: I see that, with this solution it dynamically appends href to the anchor element. The URL is visible when I hover the mouse over the link. Though this works, I want to avoid showing the entire URL in the link itslef. One of the primary reasons I wanted a jQuery solution.

Comment: @KevinRage It is easy to see that URL anyway.  If you want to do it through the window.location - http://jsfiddle.net/m9vzoxa0/

Comment: Yes, thats the solution krozo recommended. (In the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is looking for an ID

```
$('#emailLink')
```

But you have only specified the name.

Add `id="emaillink"` to the anchor tag.

Comment: Updated my post. Its typo.

Comment: This should have been a comment rather than an answer! :-)

Comment: Why is that?  It answered your question "Why doesn't this work?"  How was I supposed to know you had a typo.

Comment: Based on the question. Like the others commented out.. Please check the comments from others. Even if its the way you entered, it does not work.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need any javascript/jQuery at all for this, just the following HTML should do:

```
<a href="mailto:test@theearth.com?subject=Circle Around&body=Some blah" name="emailLink">Email</a>
```

Comment: I know how to put it directly in href. I needed it using jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: The OP noted  he needed jQuery.