# jQuery function and Page Reload issue (maybe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, jstl

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26104378/668650) code (accepted solution).
This code snipped loads from a js file. When I put a breakpoint at this function, I see that this function getting called when the page (that includes it) is loaded.

After the initial page load, when I choose an option in this page, that anchor element is reloaded (Ajax) exactly same (js file does not reload) as part of the piece of data. However, now when I click on anchor link, it does not fire / open the outlook window.

Is it something about jQuery functionality that I am mis reading/using?
How do I resolve this?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, if the element is reloaded you'll need to rebind the click event to it. Alternatively to the way you are doing it you could bind to the window/body and just specify the `id` as the selector like `$('body').on('click', '#emailLink', function () {});`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Goose that may be the thing. Let me try that

Comment: @Goose well, I guess I am lost a bit. Can you write a sample snippet?

Comment: Alright, @Goose. I just tried yours and it works! Please write that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @3rror404 I guess this question explains a problem that I didn't find an answer for easily, or rather do not know how to search. if I was aware of event Bidning/rebinding thing, I wouldn't be posting this question in the first place. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element is reloaded you'll need to rebind the click event to it.

Alternatively to the way you are doing it you could bind to the window/body and just specify the `id` as the selector like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#emailLink', function (event) {
    // your code here...
});
```